# puppet notify Exec doesn't working

Tags: ruby, linux, module, exec, puppet

Here is my code, don't worry about variable which is already set in original code. I am just putting small snippet here to show you what its doing. Following code updating file `/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf` but not triggering `notify` or `Exec` to reload file. what is wrong here?

```
$sysctl_config = "/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf"

exec { 'update_sysctl_shmall':
          unless  => "grep -q ^kernel.shmall ${sysctl_config}",
          command => "/bin/echo \"kernel.shmall = ${shmall}\" >> ${sysctl_config}",
        }

        file { '/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf':
          ensure => present,
          notify  => Exec['reload_sysctl']
        }

        exec { 'reload_sysctl':
          provider    => shell,
          command => '/bin/sysctl --system',
          logoutput => 'on_failure',
          refreshonly => true,
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
file { '/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf':
   ensure => present,
   notify  => Exec['reload_sysctl']
}
```

only ensures that `/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf` file exists. If the file exist it will do nothing, that's why `Exec` was not triggered to reload the file.
Please check the following links about notifications in puppet [1](http://www.puppetcookbook.com/posts/restart-a-service-when-a-file-changes.html),[2](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/17036/notify-and-subscribe-with-refreshonly-not-working-in-exec-resource/).

**UPDATE:**

Consider using [audit](https://puppetlabs.com/blog/all-about-auditing-with-puppet) metaparemeter:

```
file { '/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf':
    audit  => 'content',
    ensure => present,
    notify => Exec['reload_sysctl']
}
```

Comment: i want whenever `/etc/sysctl.d/pgsql.conf` file update or modify it will run `/bin/sysctl --system` command to reload file the file for system.

Comment: I updated my answer, please check if audit parameter works for you.